# 落ちしないかなあって思ってる sentence breakdown

Tags: grammar, syntax, sentence-final-particles, quotes

> 髪を染めたんですけど、すでに黒髪が恋しくて、早く色落ちしないかなあって思ってるだけです

I don't understand 落ちしないかなあって思ってる from the above quote.

1. Is 落ち acting as a noun here with しない attached? is this different from  落ちない？
2. What does かなあって mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's, word by word,

- 色落ち: color loss,
- しない: (negation of する),
- か: (questioning particle),
- なぁ: (sentence ending particle that stands for your inner thought),
- って: (quotation particle)
- 思ってる

As a whole, " I'm thinking "isn't it going to lose color?" ", in short, "I'm wondering if it loses color". Actually, it implies that you hope it loses color early in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, but one more question. How can you tell that it implies you hope it loses color early as opposed to "I'm wondering if it loses color"?
Ts that implication related to "なぁ"

Comment: S/he is saying 黒髪が恋しくて: I miss black hair.  なぁ is optional and neutral in this regard, though it enhances some emphatic feel. When it works positively, it conveys longing feel, otherwise worrisome feel.